# How does diffraction in a CD work?

Tags: visible-light, diffraction

From my shallow understanding of diffraction, my notes say that a CD acts as a diffraction grating that produces rainbow colors. In Young’s double slit experiment, we see the fringes on a screen. For the CD, are our eyes the equivalent of the screen in Young’s double slit experiment? How does this work?